# Cocos2D: Reusing a CCSequence stored in a CCArray

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a problem with an action performed by a sprite. I have one CCSequence in a CCArray and I have an scheduled method (is called every 5 seconds) that make the sprite run the action. The action is performed correctly only the first time (the first 5 seconds), after that, the action do whatever it wants lol.

Here is the code:

In .h ->

```
@interface PowerUpLayer : CCLayer {
    PowerUp *powerUp;
    CCArray *trajectories;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCArray *trajectories;
```

In .mm ->

```
@implementation PowerUpLayer

@synthesize trajectories;

-(id)init
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        [self createTrajectories];
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        [self schedule:@selector(spawn:) interval:5];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)createTrajectories
{
    self.trajectories = [CCArray arrayWithCapacity:1];

    //Wave trajectory
    ccBezierConfig firstWave, secondWave;

    firstWave.controlPoint_1 = CGPointMake([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width + 30, [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height / 2);//powerUp.sprite.position.x, powerUp.sprite.position.y);
    firstWave.controlPoint_2 = CGPointMake([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width - ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width / 4), 0);
    firstWave.endPosition = CGPointMake([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width / 2, [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height / 2);

    secondWave.controlPoint_1 = CGPointMake([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width / 2, [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height / 2);
    secondWave.controlPoint_2 = CGPointMake([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width / 4, [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height);

    secondWave.endPosition = CGPointMake(-30, [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height / 2);

    id bezierWave1 = [CCBezierTo actionWithDuration:1 bezier:firstWave];
    id bezierWave2 = [CCBezierTo actionWithDuration:1 bezier:secondWave];

    id waveTrajectory = [CCSequence actions:bezierWave1, bezierWave2, [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setInvisible:)], nil];

    [self.trajectories addObject:waveTrajectory];
    //[powerUp.sprite runAction:bezierForward];

    //        [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:3 position:CGPointMake(-[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width - powerUp.sprite.contentSize.width, 0)]
    //[powerUp.sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:bezierWave1, bezierWave2, [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setInvisible:)], nil]];

}

-(void)setInvisible:(id)sender
{
    if(powerUp != nil)
    {
        [self removeChild:sender cleanup:YES];
        powerUp = nil;
    }
}
```

This is the scheduled method:

```
-(void)spawn:(ccTime)dt
{
    if(powerUp == nil)
    {
        powerUp = [[PowerUp alloc] initWithType:0];

        powerUp.sprite.position = CGPointMake([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width + powerUp.sprite.contentSize.width, [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].height / 2);

        [self addChild:powerUp.sprite z:-1];

        [powerUp.sprite runAction:((CCSequence *)[self.trajectories objectAtIndex:0])];
    }
}
```

I don't know what is happening; I never modify the content of the CCSequence after the first time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCAction classes are one-shot. Once they've run, they don't reset their state. Anything can happen if you re-run an action a second time.

There's an [open issue requesting reusable actions](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/issues/detail?id=698) that's been there for over 2 years now. Some suggest to simply call the action's initWith… method again to reset its state, but [that's against good practices and may be downright dangerous](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6630#post-39146) if the particular action is retaining objects. You may end up with memory leaks, or worse.

The solution: re-create the sequence every time you need it. There's currently no safer alternative.

Comment: Hi Stephen, in your book you mention storing actions and using them again; I assume this is actually not something you suggest, despite your documentation of it?

Comment: Thanks, Steffen! I'll do that :D

Comment: Hey Steffen! What do you think about the solution given by Jack in: [GameDev Stack Exchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26511/cocos2d-adding-a-ccsequence-to-a-ccarray). I posted that question at the same time over there. I've tested that solution and it works but I want to know how safe it is. Thank you very much!